# Curve with CorePlot

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I want to plot one graph in which curve & line drawing both. I used scatterPlot. How to draw curve with Coreplot.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no option to have curved lines on a Core Plot scatter plot. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=156) for details. Until this is added, you might be able to fake it by adding intermediate points to your plot that approximate the desired curve.

Eric